# c# how to make instantiation more abstract?

Tags: c#, class, abstraction

I am currently writing a VSTO for Excel but this would apply to other applications, too. The app is for a number of sites, so I am writing core logic and site-specific logic. I am trying to keep all site-specific logic in a single subfolder to make it easier to exchange between sites.

VSTOs have a class called `ThisAddIn.cs`. It instantiates a class called `AddInUtilities`. Mine looks like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class AddInUtilities : IAddInUtilities
{
    public void ImportData()
    {
        var activeWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
        if (activeWorksheet == null) return;

        var loadCsv = new CsvImporter();  
        if (loadCsv.IsNotCancelled) loadCsv.AndImportIndexDataInto(activeWorksheet);
    }
}
```

My `CsvImporter` class is site-specific. It is based on an abstract class, which in turn is based on an interface, which allowed me to move everything that is core logic in the importer away from the site-specific subfolder.

What I can't get my head around is how to make the instantiation of my class

```
var loadCsv = new CsvImporter();
```

abstract? I obviously cannot instantiate the interface or abstract class. I could move this class into the site-specific code, but then my `ThisAddIn.cs`, which refers to this class will need to refer to site-specific code (or at least use the namespace of that subfolder).

The only way around that, that I can think of, would be to move the files physically into the subfolder but leave the namespace as is. Is there a better way? I feel I am missing something.

Comment: Have you considered using [SOLID design principles?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: @Aron, That's like saying "Have you considered using Object-Oriented programming"

Comment: @Aron What do you mean? Most of my logic is based on SOLID.. well, as much as I can adhere to it.

Comment: How about: `AbstractClass loadCsv = new CsvImporter()` Then you can pass around `loadCsv` as an `AbstractClass`. You can do that with the interface identity, too.

Comment: [Activator.CreateInstance Method (Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) allow you to create a type dynamically.  I don't know if it's available in VSTO

Comment: @user5226582 It is a good go to, yes...with OOP, I would be referring to one of the 4 pillars of OOP. But in this case...SOLID's DP seems to be very much the way to go...

Comment: If you can redesign this into generic you could make something like : `public void ImportData<TImporter>() where TImporter : BaseImporter`.

Comment: @Aron What I'm saying is that it's vague. Op had a specific question.

Comment: @m.rogalski I like your thinking. The class is pretty small. Might be a good way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make loadCsv a class property and push the needed object from the site specific code:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class AddInUtilities : IAddInUtilities
{
    ICsvImporter CsvImporter = null;

    public void ImportData()
    {
        var activeWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
        if (activeWorksheet == null) return;

        if (CsvImporter != null && CsvImporter.IsNotCancelled) 
        {
             CsvImporter.AndImportIndexDataInto(activeWorksheet);
        }
    }
}

public class SiteSpecificClass
{
    public void SiteImportMethod()
    {
        var addinUtility = new AddInUtilities();
        addinUtility.CsvImporter = new CsvImporter();
        addinUtility.ImportData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace that with the name I gave to the instance variable. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like what I am after, but there is a hook missing somewhere. What is calling the `SiteImportMethod`?

Comment: The `AddInUtilities.ImportData()` method is called from some point in your code. I assume from a site specific class. That is what I tried to show with my mockup class. So don't call `SiteImportMethod` but instead use this code in the place where you usually just call ÀddInUtilities.ImportData`

Comment: Thank you @Romano Zumbé  - the problem is, that the `AddInUtilities.ImportData()` is called from the `ThisAddIn.cs` class which is the VSTO class, so it would push the specific class even further up the chain. I've ended up leaving it for the time being, because I needed to get the project finished, but I'll revisit this one day.